# Saving and deleting data from the model for a Custom Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with custom cell. Each cell has 3 `textfields` which contain - Name, Age, Date of birth. Each cell has a cross button, clicking which will delete that cell. Also the last cell which is being displayed has a plus button in addition, clicking which will generate a new cell below it. Now the last cell recently created will have the plus button.

I have a model class `"StudentInfo"` which represents the data present in each cell. In the `ViewController.m` file, which contains this tableView, i save the data in a `NSMutableDictionary`. What is the appropriate way to save the data?

In my case, i have a `NSMutableDictionary`, which contains row number as key and the student info as value. Whenever the plus button is pressed, i save the visible cells. Also when delete button is pressed, i remove the appropriate key from the model and the dictionary is changed to reflect the new info.

In the `didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath` method, the data is also saved.

This implementation is currently buggy. What is the appropriate way to handle this situation?

```
    -(void) saveVisibleCellsData
{
    NSArray *cells = [myTable visibleCells];
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in cells)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForCell:cell];
        [self saveCellFromViewToModel:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

- (IBAction)btnPlusPressed:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:myTable];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    BOOL isDataValid = [self validateDataInCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (isDataValid) {
        NSArray *cells = [myTable visibleCells];
        for (UITableViewCell *cell in cells)
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForCell:cell];
            [self saveCellFromViewToModel:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        ++numOfItems;
        [myTable reloadData];
    }
}

- (IBAction)deleteCellButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *tmpCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[button superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForCell:tmpCell];

    rowBeingDeleted = indexPath.row;
    NSArray *cells = [myTable visibleCells];

    for (UITableViewCell *cell in cells)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForCell:cell];
        [self saveCellFromViewToModel:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    NSArray *tmpArry = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];

    --numOfItems;
    [myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArry withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];


    NSString *keyForLastObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zd", ([dictionaryWithCellsData count]-1)];

    NSInteger initCount = [dictionaryWithCellsData count];
    for (NSInteger counter = indexPath.row ; counter < initCount ; counter++)
    {
        NSString *keyCounter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zd", counter];
        NSString *keyCounterPlusOne = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zd", (counter+1)];

        if ((counter+1) != initCount)
        {
            id tmpObject = [dictionaryWithCellsData objectForKey:keyCounterPlusOne];
            [dictionaryWithCellsData setObject:tmpObject forKey:keyCounter];
        }

    }

    [dictionaryWithCellsData removeObjectForKey:keyForLastObject];

    [myTable reloadData];  
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (rowBeingDeleted == -1)
    {
            [self saveCellFromViewToModel:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];     
    }
    else if (rowBeingDeleted == indexPath.row)
    {
        rowBeingDeleted = -1;
    }

}
```

`saveCellFromViewToModel` function stores the Student info. against the row number passed in a NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: Can you post the code what have u tried?

Comment: @Uma added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following thing

1) The step is to create `NSArray` of students info objects instead of storing it in `NSDictionary`

2) If you are using webservice to fetch the data. For fetching data you should send request in view didLoad & after receiving response save it in objects.Make the array of Object. After that reload your tableView  & apply data to cells

3) When you press the cross button , remove the row  like this

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

4) When you remove row also remove the respective object from array.
Fetch that object at particular indexpath.

```
[arrayStudents removeObjectIdenticalTo:studentInfo];
```

5) Instead of adding plus button as row you can add it on  footer view

Comment: When should the data be saved?

Comment: If you are using webservice to fetch the data.For fetching data you should send request in view didLoad & after receiving response save it in objects.Make the array of Object. After that reload your tableView  & apply data to cells

Comment: Also, if user scrolls to a row for which they have saved the info. and update the info., how to appropriately reflect the new changes in the model?

Comment: Data is not fetched from a webservice. It is a form where user may create multiple cells and fill their choices.

Comment: You can save the data when user tap on plus button, fill all credentials & say save..after save make sure you reload table view.

Comment: If you want to persist data permanently you can also store it in Db

Comment: This is what has been done. But suppose that the user entered their data in the last cell, and scrolled down such that the last cell became invisible. It's data would not have been saved and hence could not be recovered.

Comment: You can save data of text fields in global temporary object